# Initialising a C vector pointer throws a bus error but initialising a vector doesn't

Tags: c, pointers, gcc

This C code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    int *a;
    int sz, cap;
} Vector;

void vector_init(Vector *v)
{
    v->a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    v->sz = 0;
    v->cap = 1;
}

int main()
{
    Vector *v;
    vector_init(v);
}
```

throws a bus error.
but replacing `Vector *v` with `Vector v` and `vector_init(v)` with `vector_init(&v)` solves it. why?

Comment: `v` (when declard as `Vector *v`) is not initialized. It points nowhere.

Answer (score 3):

When you write `Vector *v`, you're creating an uninitialized pointer to `Vector`. There's no object of type `Vector` that exists in this program. `v` is uninitialized, dereferencing it is undefined behaviour, and in practice will often lead to a crash because of an illegal memory access.

Defining a pointer does not automatically create memory for an object of the pointed-to type, you need to do that.

Doing `Vector v` with `vector_init(&v)` works because you're creating an actual object of type `Vector`, then passing in a pointer to that.

To have an object of type `Vector *`, you have to give it an object to point to. That could be by explicitly creating an object:

```
Vector v_storage;
Vector *v = &v_storage;
vector_init(v);
```

Though it'd be silly to do the above in actual code, you should just stick with the `Vector v` and `vector_init(&v)`.

You could also create storage for a `Vector` using a dynamic memory allocation using `malloc`, if that was appropriate for what you want to write, and then clean it up with `free` later.

Comment: Not a very good idea to have base structure having static or automatic storage duration and data having dynamic storage duration. If you want more than one vector? Allocate dynamically both.

Comment: @0___________ I'm trying to directly answer their question about why their way doesn't work, but directly creating the object does. I note in my answer that it would be silly to do that.

Answer (score 0):

#### Design your API to parallel malloc() and free()

The way to handle objects in C is to ***take** a pointer on create* and *pass a pointer on destroy*. That is, you should write functions that parallel `malloc()` and `free()` (or, in my personal preference, free-and-null):

```
Vector * Vector_create( size_t size );
Vector * Vector_destroy( Vector * v );
```

They are used thus:

```
Vector * v0   = Vector_create( 0 );    // create an empty vector
Vector * v100 = Vector_create( 100 );  // create a vector with 100 elements
```

```
v0 = Vector_destroy( v0 );  // free and null
Vector_destroy( v100 );     // zeroing your pointer is optional
```

Useful operations on your vector should likewise have proper signatures:

```
Vector * Vector_copy( Vector * v );  // deep copy a vector
int * Vector_at( Vector * v, size_t index );  // etc
void Vector_push_back( Vector * v, int x );  // may resize the vector!
```

```
Vector * v2 = Vector_copy( v );  // create new vector v2 == v
*Vector_at( v, 7 ) = 123456;     // assign value to v[7] = 123456
Vector_push_back( v, 42 );       // increase size of v and assign 42 to new element (possible capacity change)
```

#### FAM

Depending on the object, I sometimes like to do as 0___________ did [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71008538/2706707) (use a *flexible array member*), but this does complicate your calling code a little because it removes a level of indirection — you must now pass references to your object as argument to every function (for consistency, even for functions that don’t need it, because some do!):

```
Vector * v = Vector_create( 0 );
Vector_push_back( &v, 42 );  // because v may be reallocated!
printf( "%d\n", *Vector_at( &v, 0 ) );
free( v );  // this might still be worth hiding behind a Vector_free() function
```

Answer (score -2):

1. I would use flexible array members instead of pointers.
2. In your code you need to pass **double pointer** In this case it is not the best idea, it is much better to use function return value instead side effects
3. You need to allocate the memory for the structure itself, bot only for the data.
4. Use correct types for sizes and indexes.
5. Check for allocation errors!!
6. Do not cast the result of malloc

```
typedef struct
{
    size_t sz, cap;
    int a[];
} Vector;


Vector *vector_init(void)
{
    Vector *vi = malloc(sizeof(*vi) + sizeof(vi->a[0]));
    
    if(vi)
    {
        vi->sz = 0;
        vi->cap = 1;
    }
    return vi;
}
```

If you do not want to return the value

```
void vector_init(Vector **vi)
{
    *vi = malloc(sizeof(**vi) + sizeof((*vi)->a[0]));
    
    if(*vi)
    {
        (*vi)->sz = 0;
        (*vi)->cap = 1;
    }
}
```

and usage

```
int main()
{
    Vector *v;
    vector_init(&v);
}
```